cannot find ../target/types/transfer_hook library
There is a reference for the below library in all Transfer hook examples. However, I have no idea how to install that in our local
import { TransferHook } from "../target/types/transfer_hook";
Please help
Cannot find module '../target/types/transfer_hook' or its corresponding type declarations.
